# Insert output from txt file as next command

Tags: command-line

I wonder if it’s possible to get the output from a file as the next command.

Example:

Instead of:

```
myUserName 09:52:52
~ cat info.txt
ssh userName@student-shell-1.sys.school.tld
```

I'm looking for:

```
myUserName 09:52:53
~ cat info.txt
~ ssh userName@student-shell-1.sys.school.tld
```

I hope this makes sense.

PS. I'm new to bash so not asking to solve a problem or something. Just wanted to know out of curiosity.

Thanks!

Comment: " as the next command."  to do what? execute it on the remote server?

Answer (score 1):

Commands in a text file can be executed with the `sh` command. For example:

```
sh info.txt
```

Some other alternative forms with slightly different effects are:

```
.  info.txt
```

or

```
source  info.txt
```

Note that, the text file (`info.txt` in your example) is called a *script file*  and ***all*** the contents of this file will be executed by the the `sh` command. In other words, the text file may contain more than one command (typically one per line) and all these commands will be executed *sequentially*.

The script file may contain extra control flow commands (conditional, looping, subroutine calling, etc.) that will be processed by the **shell interpreter**. To find out the currently used shell interpreter use the `ps` command. At the end of the line following the header you will see the shell interpreter, which is typically `bash` or `sh`.

For more information, you should Google "*bash programming*" or "*shell programming*".

Answer (score 0):

```
cat "info.txt" | ssh userName@student-shell-1.sys.school.tld "cat > file.remote.txt"
```

opens `info.txt` and pipes it to the ssh process, and you will have a file.remote.txt on the server. Adding `&& ./file.remote.txt` would execute the contents if it is executabble.